# Do Stack Exchange websites use cookies?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, cookies

Does Stack Exchange use cookies? If so, how do they comply with the European cookie law?

Comment: They're not a EU based business, so they probably don't need to comply with European data protection provisions, no?

Comment: I understand your perspective @Pëkka however in my opinion to comply with European electronic privacy laws. Companies must gain the consent of users before serving them with cookies.

Comment: Some cookies don’t require explicit consent. Not sure whether SE only uses those.

Comment: Well, maybe they don't *have* to comply with the cookie provision. Good for them if they don't; it seems incredibly silly. I haven't seen it have any effect except creating nuisances in people's browsing experience - sometimes well, sometimes not so well implemented.

Comment: Imho the EU cookie law is one of the most idiotic laws of the past decade. It was passed by people who were absolutely clueless about what they were voting on.

Comment: @Stijn I couldn't agree more. However some tech companies i.e. google aggregate too much info on users. They go through our emails, they know our location and our search history for like decades.

Comment: Thankfully, SO doesn't annoy us with idiotic cookie warnings that some dope in an EU court thought was a good idea.

Comment: @Seth `However some tech companies i.e. google aggregate too much info on users` yup, and the beauty of the Cookie Warning is that it's doing exactly zero about that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Stack Exchange uses cookies. It stores information on your information to remember some of your information. E.g : Login information, your account details etc.,

[image: Window from Firefox browser to show security information about cookies]

Above image is the information for a Firefox browser which I use.

Consider this as a partial answer.

You can read more about the use of your information in [Stack Exchange, Inc. Official Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)

Comment: I appreciate your perspective, however in my opinion according to European privacy laws companies must gain the consent of users before serving them with cookies.

Comment: The policy might be revised to comply with the European privacy laws. It is still not known.

Comment: @Seth There is also a list of exceptions, like cookies used for authentication, etc. I don't believe we actually use cookies in a way that the law applies to us. But I'm also not familiar with what all of our cookies are for, so I couldn't say.